# Setting up a webView with undefined frame (programmatic layout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I'm trying to load an HTML string into a web view on iOS (via loadHTMLString: baseURL:]

I want to define my webView like this:

```
- (UIWebView *)webView {

if (!_webView) {

    _webView = [UIWebView new];
    _webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    _webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES;
    _webView.delegate = self;

    [self.contentView addSubview:_webView];
}
return _webView;
}
```

I need it to appear within a subview because I want other things to appear in the same view. Problem is, nothing shows up. I've tested out a few things:

I cleared out the view aside from a scroll view, a content view within it, and the web view (using constraintWithVisualFormat, constraintWithItem, and lazy loading). Nothing shows up.

Then I tried clearing out absolutely everything and replacing _webView = [UIWebView new] with _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
This worked. Nonetheless, it doesn't solve my issue, because I want multiple things underneath one view.

So, how do I get the webView to show up at all if I am unable to define the frame as the entire view in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is entirely possible. Maybe you are adding constrains the wrong way or you  html is not 100% in size of your webview.

I would suggest you to use a library to deal with constrains, which is much more intuitive and less error prone. For example you could consider [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)